# Return Enumerable value from Class in linq?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq

i need Enumarable value from below class but give error

```
   public static  Enumerable  LoadDataByName(string name)
        {
            List<StuffDepartman> Stuff = (List<StuffDepartman>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Stuffs"];
            var stuffs = from s in Stuff select s;

             stuffs = from s in Stuff where s.Name = name select s.Name;

            return stuffs.AsEnumerable();
        }
```

But Give me error:  **System.Linq.Enumerable': static types cannot be used as return types**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET 3.5, there exists a static `Enumerable` existing in `System.Linq`, which contains extension methods for manipulating `IEnumerable`s - this is not what you want to (or clearly *can*) return. Change it to `IEnumerable`, which is the non-generic enumerable class (and what I think you intend), and all should work fine.

Even better, use the generic version of `IEnumerable`, as such:

```
public static IEnumerable<StuffDepartman> LoadDataByName(string name)
{
    var stuffs = (List<StuffDepartman>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Stuffs"];

    return (from s in stuffs where s.Name == name select s.Name);
}
```

Also, note that you don't need the call to `AsEnumerable` before returning, since `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and the former can be implicitly casted to the latter. The `=` needed to be changed to `==`, since you want to use the equality rather than assigment operator here. The other changes are just tidying up.

Comment: your codes give me error:The non-generic type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: Oops. Sorry, missed out the 'I' - it should be IEnumerable.

Comment: you correct but "s.Name = name" give me:  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: Change that to `s.Name = name`. In C#, = is the assignment operator, while == is the equality operator.

Comment: Related to last comment of me: s.Name defined "string" also name defined as string.

Comment: @ykaratoprak: Yeah, I presumed that. If I were to guess, you come from a BASIC/VB background, where both the equality and assignment operators are `=` - this is not the case in C#.

Answer (score 1):

`System.Linq.Enumerable` is a static class with a bunch of extension methods defined on it. You perhaps meant to return `IEnumerable<string>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerable is a static class, what you want to do is return an IEnumerable:

```
    public static  IEnumerable<string>  LoadDataByName(string name)
    {
      //do stuff
    }
```

I'm assuming s.Name in your example is a string, which is why the method should return IEnumerable<string>. If it's another type, then change it to that type....

EDIT: Ok, I guess it's not a string. Change it to:

```
    public static  IEnumerable<StuffDepartman>  LoadDataByName(string name)
    {
      //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Error1: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: Error2:Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BLL.StuffDepartman>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)